# C# "base" keyword and template

Tags: c#, templates, keyword, radix

I am trying to create a new class called Battlefield. It supposed to derive from the class Environment and take all the methods and variables from that Environment class using the base keyword. Anyone knows how to use that base keyword? I've searched everywhere on Google, but most of what I came up with were not as helpful.

My environment class is an abstract class, and it has the following variable

```
        protected List<ENTITY> entities = new List<ENTITY>();
```

Its constructor

```
        public ENVIRONMENT()
        {
            entities = new List<ENTITY>();
        }

        public ENVIRONMENT(List<ENTITY> entities)
        {
            this.entities = entities;
        }
```

and the following methods...

```
        public void AddEntity(ENTITY e)
        {
        }

        public List<ENTITY> Population
        {
            get { return entities; }
        }

        public void run()
        {
            // run method
        }

        public void step(int seed)
        {
           // step method
        }
```

}

Comment: You're saying the official documentation was unhelpful in explaining the keyword?

Comment: Yes. I couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You only need the `base` keyword if you have a method in `Battlefield` that overrides the method of the same name in `Environment`, and you want the value from the `Environment` method instead of the value from the `Battlefield` override.  For example in `Battlefield`:

```
public class Battlefield : Environment {
    public List<ENTITY> Population
    {
      get
      {
        var epop = base.Population;
        return epop.Union(Casualties);
      }
    }

    public List<ENTITY> Casualties
    {
      get { return this.casualties; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know. Someone out there is trying to downvote questions and answers without giving a reason.

Comment: @John I'll try that approach. Thank you.